# Object refrence and type casting in java

Tags: java

```
class A{
    int foo=10;
}
class B extends A{
    int foo=10;
}
class Test{
    public static void main(String [] args){
         A a=new B();
         System.out.println(a.foo);
         //System.out.println(a.getClass());
     }
}
```

In this case `10` is output. If I am not wrong, then this is because the `a` variable is of type `A` and variable assignment is static binding, and static binding is done at compile time by looking at the type of the variable. Since here `a` is of type `A`, then `A`'s `int foo` is called. However when I call

```
System.out.println(a.getClass());
```

then this gives class `B`, that is `a` is of type `B`. I am confused about this. Kindly explain to me `a` is of which type and how `A`'s `int foo` is printed.
But by looking at this code

```
class A{}

class B extends A{}

class Test{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        B b=new B();
        A a=b;
        B b1=(B)a; // compiles and run fine (a is of type B)
    }
}
```

How is this possible? What's happening here? First `b` is of type `B` then in the second line `a` becomes of type `A`, as `A a=..` is written but `a.getClass()` gives that it is of type `B`. How? If `a` is of type `B` then why is it calling `A`'s `int foo` in the first example? Kindly explain both examples.

Also, does type casting change references or do any other stuff?

Comment: The object on the heap stays the same. The way you refer to it changes.

Comment: you are shadowing the variable, there is no overriding for a variable. btw there isn´t any other possible output then 10 ;). In this case you are simply accessing the variable `foo` from `A`, because that´s how your variable is defined. Since there is no overriding for variables, the type of the declaration is important if you are directly accessing variables from a type.

Comment: *In this case 10 is output*: what else could it print? You're confusing the declared type of a variable, and the runtime, concrete type of the object referenced by that variable. An object never changes of type. Calling getClass() returns its concrete type. But two variables of different types can refer to the same object, because a B **is a** A.

Comment: It would be much more educational and interesting if `A.foo` was different from `B.foo`.

Comment: in A a=new B() a is of which type A or B

Comment: the reference is of type A the referenced object is of type B. a.foo gives you the field in Class A, because of the static binding. a.getClass() is determined at runtime and is an application of the method in B. See my answer a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to realise is that Java only has primitive and reference variable types.  This means when you write

```
A a =
```

The `a` is just a reference to an object (or null) not an object.

When you do

```
A a = new B();
```

there is no cast here, no work is done, no object is harmed or changed.

When you call an instance method on a class, it calls the method for the class of the object.

```
Object o = new B();
assert o.getClass() == B.class;
```

a longer example

```
B b = new B();
A a = b;
assert a == b; // always true as they point to the same object.
assert b.getClass() == B.class;
// so it makes sense that since a == b
assert a.getClass() == B.class;
```

> type casting change references or do any other stuff?

It changes the type of the reference and it doesn't do other stuff like change the type of the object.

*methods* follow inheritance, however *fields* follow the type of the reference as a field cannot be overridden, it can only be hidden.

> B b=new B(); A x=b; B b1=(B)x; // compiles and run fine (x is of type b) in this line when x is of which type

correct and you wouldn't be able to `(B)x` unless `x` was a reference to a `B`  The variables `x` is an `A` which means it must point to an `A` object or a sub-class of a `A` e.g. `B` you can write

```
B b = new B(); 
A x = b;
assert x == b; // they still point to the same object.
B b1 = (B) x;
assert b1 == b; // same object
assert x == b1; // same object.
```

No new objects are created, nor is the object changed.

Comment: B b=new B();
  A x=b;
  B b1=(B)x; // compiles and run fine (x is of type b) in this line when x is of which type

Comment: @MayankSingh correct and you wouldn't be able to `(B)x` unless `x` was a reference to a `B` I have updated my answer

Comment: A a=new B() // in this case a is of which type A or B

Comment: @MayankSingh `a` is a reference to an `A` which points to an object which is an instance of the class `B` which is a sub-class of `A` which is why `a` can be a reference to it.

Comment: A x=b;
  B b1=(B)x; // compiles and run fine (x is of type B) ...in first line x is of A type okay but in second line why it is written x is of type B .Kindly explain me this concept please

Comment: @MayankSingh please read the end of my answer again. There is only one object in your example and it can only have one class. An object never changes it's class. Why do you think the type of the object changes?

Comment: because in this line that is A x . x is of type A but when i call B b1=(B)x in this line that is (B)x . x is type casted to B means  B will now refer to X

Comment: @MayankSingh `new` creates an object, assigning one *reference* to another doesn't create a new object, it doesn't change the type of that object, it doesn't destroy the object.  There is only one object in your example, no matter how many references of different types point to it.

Comment: @MayankSingh `x` is of type A or a sub-class, it doesn't mean the object it points to is an A or even exists e.g. `A x = null;` there is no object here and `x.getClass()` will throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: in code A a=(B)x...(B)x represent that we want to cast x into B.Does it mean that we want x to be refrence variable of type B.??

Comment: @MayankSingh yes, `x` has to be an instance of `B` or a sub-class otherwise this will throw a `ClassCastException` because the cast can't actually change the type of the object. It is either the right type (in which case the cast works) or it isn't (in which case you get an Exception)

Comment: `assert a.getClass() == A.class;` is incorrect. It should be `assert a.getClass() == B.class;`

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple why it does print the `foo` of `A`, because `a` is defined as `A`. Since there is no overriding for variables you are simply accesing the variables which are accesible for the type the variable is declared, which is `A` in this case.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println(a.foo); // prints the foo of A, since a is of the type A
    A b = new B();
    System.out.println(b.foo); // prints the foo of A, since b is of the type A
    B c = new B();
    System.out.println(c.foo); // prints the foo of B, since c is of the type B
}
```

In the end it´s called shadowing what you are doing there. Your class `B` has a variable with the same name as `A`. Since they are not overridable you are able to hide `foo` of `A`, if your variable is of the type `B`, where you are accessing `foo` of `B`

Comment: in code A a=(B)x...(B)x represent that we want to cast x into B.Does it mean that we want x to be refrence variable of type B.??

Comment: @MayankSingh no, it means that `x` is actually a instance of `B` or any subclass of it. This would most likely only make sense if `x` would be of the type `Object` in this rather tiny example. But i don´t get where you got this piece of code from.

Comment: but somehwere i read that type casting generally means we are changing reference

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to Javas polymorphic behavior and dynamic (late) vs. static (early) binding.
The access to all the member variables in Java follows static binding. That means you have no polymorphism in this case. Instance Methods are dynamically bound. The instance method used for an invocation will be determined by the class of the object, not by the reference type. For example:

```
public class Main {

    static class A{
        String foo="A";

        public String getFoo() {
            return foo;
        }
    }
    static class B extends A{
        String foo="B";

        @Override
        public String getFoo() {
            return foo;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        A a=new B();
        System.out.println(a.foo); // prints A
        System.out.println(a.getFoo()); // prints B
        System.out.println(a.getClass()); // prints Main$B
    }
}
```

[Late binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding)

[Early Binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding)

[Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))